# PHP Alternatives to Remote File Inclusion

Tags: php

One of our clients has two very similar websites that we are performing lead tracking on. Currently, I have copies of the files that make this work on both sites, with a single file having the variances that make it unique.

My question is: is there a way to allow both sites to share files? Changing allow_url_fopen is not an option.

---

@Chris Yes,  and both sites dump data into the same MySQL db.

Comment: Are both sites hosted on the same server?

Comment: Is it at all possible to run them on the same server with different virtual hosts?

Comment: @Michael They are on the same server, but with aliased hosts.
site1.com -> ourserver.com/site1
site2.com -> ourserver.com/site2

Comment: @Chris Turn your comment into an answer so I can mark it. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sites are hosted on the same server, you can simply use an `include/require` statement to share the file.

Place the file in a location that is readable for both site configurations, then supply the full path to the file.

For instance:

```
/www <-- web root
  /siteA <-- first site
  /siteB <-- second site
  /libs  <-- location to store files to be shared by both sites
```

... then use `require_once('/www/libs/file_to_share.php);`

Answer (score 1):

If the sites are hosted on the same server and the host allows it, you can simply `chdir()` to the correct (shared) directory at the beginning of one of the sites' scripts.

Alternatively, you can get the file(s) with cURL, dump it/them to a file and then `include()` it/them.

Including remote files is slower no matter how you do it, and not really recommended for a web page as it will massively increase the server traffic/load and page load time.

**EDIT** Based on what you say about the way the domains are working, you could also point both sites to the same location examine `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to determine which site-specific file to include.

Comment: I really like the cURL approach to this. I am thinking of ways this would be more useful.